# Android Seekbar

Tags: android, seekbar

I'm using `seekbar` in android. I have made an array in the `string.xml` I want that when i move the seek bar the value of array should be printed on the textview as long as i move the seek bar the value on text view shoul be changed.

Here is my code -

**Java File**

```
public class SliderActivity extends Activity 
{
    SeekBar seekbar;
    TextView txt1,txt2;
    String item[];
    int count=0;
    File file;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        item=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myArray);
        seekbar=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        txt1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        txt2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener()
        {
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar)
            {
                txt2.setText("seekbar has been stop");
            }
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar bar)
            {
                txt2.setText("seekbar has started");
            }
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar bar,int paramInt, boolean paramBoolean)
            {
                txt1.setText("");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: how much item you have in array

Answer (score 2):

Considering you have five elements in your array, Do something like this.

```
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
        if (progress <= 20) {


            speed.setText("your Text");
        } else if (progress >= 21 && progress <= 40) {

            speed.setText("your Text");
        } else if (progress >= 41 && progress <= 60) {

            speed.setText("your Text");
        } else if (progress >= 61 && progress <= 80) {

            speed.setText("your Text");
        } else if (progress >= 81 && progress <= 100) {
            speed.setText("your Text");
        }
    }

    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

});
```

Comment: if i ll consider 50 elements instead of 5 then what should i do.

Comment: Simple divide the progress percent by two. Then round the value. set the array value based on the rounded value

Answer (score 0):

You can use `seekBar.setMax(max)` where max is = to the no of item in array

and `paramInt` to get the item from array